# React-native BigInt value to a number (ccxt)

Tags: react-native, bigint, react-native-0.68.2

Good afternoon, connected the ccxt library to the project, trying to get the data, it gives an error.

```
LogBox.js:173 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number
```

I tried to comment out the code in the library: node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-preset/src/configs/main.js

```
// if (!isHermes && (isNull || src.indexOf("**") !== -1)) {   
//  extraPlugins.push([   
//  require("@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator"),   
//   ]);
// }
```

Didn't help ;(

Stack:

```
"react": "17.0.2",  
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"ccxt": "^1.90.57",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7LNb.png)